# Is it reasonable/possible to use pre-scores as predictors of change?

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, pre-post-comparison

In change analyses (of any variable, from pre to post) we usually controll for the pre-score, as it may affect the rate of change. However, what if I am especially interested in the *effect* of the pre score on the rate of change, like

Diff(post - pre) = a + b*pre.

What if I am especially interested in b? Is the model above reasonable or are there any problems with that?

In multilevel-analysis of longitudinal data there is a correlation coefficient for the relation between the initial level (intercept) and the rate of change (slope). Thats the information I need, but in an ordinary regression model.

Comment: Why not do a multilevel analysis?

Comment: Take a look at latent difference scores, which is a SEM technique. In that framework, you can predict the latent difference/change from T0 to T1 by levels of T0. See https://doi.org./10.1177/0265407517718387 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595777/multilevel-model-with-two-timepoints

Comment: As mentioned by @ErikRuzek, a latent difference score approach would be preferred because the observed difference (change) score variable typically contains a lot of measurement error variance (unreliability). This can lead to substantial bias in the estimated b coefficient. The latent change score approach corrects for error. See also: https://youtu.be/0QUuP2BoMlk

Comment: A problem is that the change score is necessarily correlated with the `pre` value. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478310/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/509452/28500), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional references for the latent change/latent difference score approach:

McArdle, J. J. (2009). Latent variable modeling of differences and changes with longitudinal data. *Annual Review of Psychology, 60*, 577-605.

Raykov, T. (1993). A structural equation model for measuring residualized change and discerning patterns of growth or decline. *Applied Psychological Measurement, 17*, 53-71.

Steyer, R., Eid, M., & Schwenkmezger, P. (1997). Modeling true intraindividual change: True change as a latent variable. *Methods of Psychological Research - Online, 2*, 21–33.

Steyer, R., Partchev, I., & Shanahan, M. (2000). Modeling true intra-individual change in structural equation models: The case of poverty and children's psychosocial adjustment. In T. D. Little, K. U. Schnabel & J. Baumert (Eds.), *Modeling longitudinal and multiple-group data: Practical issues, applied approaches, and specific examples* (pp. 109–126). Hillsdale, NJ: Erlbaum.